# listview navigation with arrow keys not working as it should

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have the following code which selects the next item in the listview when a control is pressed (button1).  if I click button1 to go to the next item it will work but the selected items are out of sync. to test this just click the button several times and then press either up or down on the keyboard. it doesn't go to the previous/next item as it should.

has anyone encountered this issue? what am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lv_issue
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                return;
            listView1.Focus();

            int s = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;

            listView1.Items[s].Selected = false;

            if (s < listView1.Items.Count - 1)
                s++;

            listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
            listView1.Items[s].Selected = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution - in addition to the above code one needs to set the focus to the newly selected item with

```
listview1.Items[s].Focused=true;
```

then everyting works as it should